# Use sumproduct to produce text with row and column reference in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to extract the text comment in the error produced by sumproduct in the following sheet? I expect C9 and C10 to be "Comment1" and "Comment2". This appears in the error message. Either a direct way to get the desired text or to extract the text from the error message using some JavaScript will be fine.

Here is the test sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aq4afUw29CxdOM4Yp9dgZw2wdJto8H343YMTJLXG-qM/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error occurs as you are trying to multiply text values.
If you need to get respective data from Comment column use following [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en-GB) and [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en-GB) formulas.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$H$6,MATCH($B9,$A$1:$A$6,0),MATCH(C$8,$A$1:$H$1,0))
```

See results in D9 and D10 cells in your test sheet.